# What term is used for different types of smoking (e-cigs, vapes, cigars)?

Tags: words, slang, loanwords

If someone wants to smoke a cigarette in your presence, they might ask "タバコいいっすか？". I've also heard it referred to as 煙 (kemuri). I'd imagine those terms work for cigars as well (however rare they are in japan).

My question is: what would the equivalent thing be for a vape/e-cig? Or would the same terms work just fine?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @istrasci - It appears to be essentially asking names of things as it has nothing to do with the scenario presented where someone wants to smoke in your presence or how to use expressions like いいっすか for asking permission. If this is asking for slang terms like 煙 for smoke-less types of smoking, it’s not clear from the way it is written. What do “those terms” refer to? 煙 is the only such term mentioned before it. いいっすか is just a colloquial form of いいですか and it works for pretty much anything, and タバコ is a common (i.e. not slangy) word.

Comment: @aguijonazo - Uhhh....seems pretty clear to me.  "Those terms" = "タバコ" and "煙".

Comment: @istrasci - Then, it’s like saying "タバコ is for a cigarette as everyone knows, then what’s for a vape or e-cig?" How is it different from asking names of things?

Answer (score 3):

I don't smoke, but the standard words should be:

- cigar: 葉巻{はまき}
- cigarette: タバコ(煙草) - the most common
- e-cig: 電子タバコ

A slang for (usually) cigarettes is ヤニ (due to [#2](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%84%82/#jn-222384)). E.g., ヤニ吸ってきます means *I'll be out for smoking*.